# Reproducing DEB packages of APT cache

Tags: package-management, backup, deb

I wanted to use Aptik to backup all my PPAs and packages, because at some point I may need to clean install Ubuntu (same version).

But unfortunately, before knowing about Aptik I ran `apt-get clean` commmand, so all DEB packages were gone. Is there any way to reproduce all the deb packages installed by the user (including dependency)? - so that I can use Aptik to backup properly.

Comment: Do you want to download them again?

Comment: @helio ,Of course not. If so, why would I ever use something like Aptik, and ask this question?  :)

Comment: I see difficult... However you can try running `testdisk` on your HDD and recover all the erased files on the `/var/cache/apt/archives` folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can recover these files using `testdisk`:

1. Run `testdisk`
2. Select `No Log`
3. Select the disk where Ubuntu is installed
4. Select the partition table (usually `Intel` or `GPT`)
5. Select `Analyse`
6. Select `Quick Search`
7. Highlight the root partition (usually `Linux`)
8. Press <kbd>p</kbd> key
9. Navigate to `/var/cache/apt/archives`
10. Highlight the first entry (the entry that has `.` as name)
11. Press <kbd>c</kbd> key
12. Select a location to copy these files (i.e. your home)
13. Press <kbd>c</kbd> key again to copy files.
14. Exit the program.
15. Move all the .deb files recovered to `/var/cache/apt/archives`

Answer (score 0):

Check the **[AptOnCD](http://www.howtogeek.com/110034/how-to-back-up-restore-your-installed-ubuntu-packages-with-aptoncd/)** tool. It can backup and restore all of your installed packages.